# Getting Null value Of variable in sql server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

Strange situation
In a trigger i assign a column value to variable but gives exception while inserting into other table using that variable.

e.g

**select @srNO=A.SrNo from A where id=123;

insert into B (SRNO) values (@srNo) // here it gives null**

I run above select query in query pane it works fine but in trigger it gives me null

any suggestions

ALTER PROCEDURE ProcessData 
 
@Id decimal(38,0), 
@XMLString varchar(1000),
@Phone varchar(20)
AS
DECLARE

@idoc int,
@iError int,
@Serial varchar(15),
@PhoneNumber varchar(15),

BEGIN
    COMMIT TRAN

```
EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @idoc OUTPUT,@XMLString<br/>

SELECT @iError = @@Error<br/>
         IF @iError = 0<br/>
    BEGIN<br/>
```

SELECT @Serial = convert(text,[text]) FROM OPENXML (@idoc,'',1) where nodetype = 3 and ParentId = 2

```
        IF @Serial=Valid <br/>

                      BEGIN<br/>
                            BEGIN TRAN INVALID<br/>
                            begin try <br/>
                            Declare @phoneId decimal(38,0);<br/>
                               SELECT @phoneId = B.phoneId  FROM A
        INNER JOIN B ON A.Id = B.Id WHERE A.PhoneNumber like '%'+@SenderPhone + '%'<br/>

        print @phoneId ; //gives null<br/>

            end try<br/>
            begin catch<br/>
            print Error_Message();<br/>
            end catch<br/>
```

Comment: Could you please post your complete `CREATE TRIGGER` statement?

Comment: above procedutre getting called from trigger

Comment: As Quassnoi said, can you post the full `CREATE TRIGGER`statement which calls this proc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved it there is some error in xml string reading function
e.g in openxml pattern matching

Thanks all of you for help... :)

Answer (score 1):

you should work with sets of rows in triggers, so if multiple rows are affected your code handles all rows.  This will only INSERT when the value is not null:

```
INSERT INTO B (SRNO)
SELECT A.SrNo FROM A where id=123 AND A.SrNo IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

**Neo**, are you sure, that `SELECT SrNo FROM A WHERE id = 123` returns data?
I mean, value of @srNo will not change (therefore, remain NULL) if there no records with `id = 123`

Answer (score 1):

> When you eliminate the impossible, whatever remains, however improbable, must be the truth.

The obvious answer is that at the time the trigger fires, `SrNo` is null or Id 123 does not exist. Is this for an insert trigger and is it the case that you are trying to take something that was just inserted into table `A` and push it into table `B`? If so, you should query against the `inserted` table:

```
//from an insert trigger on the table `A`
Insert B( SRNO )
Select SRNO
From inserted
Where Id = 123
```

If this is not the case, then we'd need to see the details of the Trigger itself.

Comment: no its not the case the table B is already there having primary key table from which i am fetching the key depends upon the id which is primary key of A table.
And this is in insert after trigger.

Comment: also there is also insert instead of trigger on same table

Comment: @Neo - I'm not sure what you are trying to say in your first comment. You said that the procedure you added to your post is being called from an after trigger. An after trigger on Table A or Table B? What does that instead of trigger look like? How does `@SenderPhone` ever get set? It isn't a parameter and does not appear to be declared? Can you post the actual trigger and how it calls your stored proc?

Comment: thanks thomans
there is trigger on table A that is after insert and in that this procedure is getting called.
So now the problem is solved.i found out a mistake by my teammate to read and create xml string so that we cant get proper value in to match the condition in where clause.
now  the above procedure with trigger working fine

thanks for asking..